# What is the fixed subfield of the field $\mathbb F_p(X)$ corresponding to a specific group?

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field of order $p$ ( $\Rightarrow char \mathbb F = p, \text{ and so } \mathbb F = \mathbb F_p$ ), $L = F(X)$, $\;a \in \mathbb F_p \backslash\{0\}$ and $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb F}(L)$ such that $\sigma(X) = aX$

Let $G$ be the group generated by $\sigma$. What is $G$ and what is $L^G, $ the subfield of $L$ over $ \mathbb F \text{ fixed by } G?$

My thoughts:

$\sigma^k(X) = a^kX \; \; \forall 1 \leq k \leq p-2,$ and specifically $\sigma^{p-1}(X) = a^{p-1}X = aX $ by Fermat's Little Theorem. Also by FLT we see that $\sigma^k(X) \neq X \; \; \forall k < p-1$.

So $G = \{e, \sigma, \sigma^2, \dots \sigma^{p-2}\}$ is the cyclic group of order $p-1$.

Now for $L^G,$ I'm really stuck and don't know how to approach it. I have tried to compare $\sigma^k(f) $ and $f,$ where $f \in L$ but can't really show much other than the fact that the degree of the numerator polynomial and denominator polynomial are congruent$\pmod {p-1}$.

I've also had the thought that if $f \in \mathbb F[X] \subset L$ is fixed by $G$ then $\sigma ^k(f(X)) = f(a^kX)$ so if $f(X) = a_nX^n + \dots + a_0$ then we have:

$a_na^{kn}X^n + \dots + a_1a^kX + a_0 = a_nX^n + \dots + a_1X = a_0$ Equating coefficients we get that:

$a_la^{kl} = a_l \; \forall l,k \Rightarrow \text{ either } kl \equiv 0 \pmod {p-1} \forall 1\leq k \leq p-2 \text{ or } a_l = 0$

The first condition then means that $l \equiv 2l \equiv \dots \equiv (p-2)l \pmod{p-1} \Rightarrow l \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$

This means then that $f(X) = a_{m(p-1)}X^{m(p-1)} + \dots + a_{p-1}X^{p-1} + a_0$

i.e. $f(X) \in \mathbb F[X^{p-1}] \subset \mathbb F[X] \subset L$

Similarly, I considered $\frac{1}{g(X)}, \text{ where } g(X) \in \mathbb F[X] $

$\sigma^k(\frac{1}{g(X)}) = \frac{1}{g(a^kX)} = \frac{1}{g(X)} \Rightarrow g(X) = g(a^kX)$ so as before, $g(X) \in \mathbb F[X^{p-1}]$

This then seems to imply that $L^G = \mathbb F[X^{p-1}]$

However, I have a strange suspicion that this is in fact false, but I don't know why. Is this proof valid or have I missed something? Any help you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is $L$?  And by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ do you mean $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: @Ted L is the field of rational polynomials of $\mathbb F[X = F(X)]$ and yes I do, sorry.

Comment: The fixed field of $X \mapsto a X$ is $\mathbb{F}_p(X^m)$ where $m$ is the order of $a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. In general for $m \nmid \text{char}(k)$ the Galois group of $\overline{k}(X)/\overline{k}(X^m)$ is $X \mapsto \zeta_m X$ since the minimal polynomial is $t^m - X^m = \prod_{l=1}^m (t-\zeta_m^l X)$